# PHP doesn't import all Excel files into MySqli database

Tags: php, excel, mysqli, phpspreadsheet

I have 123 Excel files which all contains information, which i want to import in my MySqli database.

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet for reading the Excel files. 
First i fetched the amount of files which have to be imported.

```
$path = "echt/";
$fi = new FilesystemIterator($path , FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$num = iterator_count($fi);
```

Then i fetched all the file names of all the files which have to be imported.

```
$filenames = array_diff(scandir($path), array('..', '.'));
$fileSystemIterator = new FilesystemIterator($path);
```

Then i did a foreach loop through all the variable `$filename`. 
So the foreach loop should actually execute all the code in the loop for each different file. 
But for some reason, of the 123 files i've got, only 87 files are being imported into the MySqli database. 
I know for sure that the information i want to import are at the same cell in each Excel file, so i can just do something like this: `$brand = $spreadsheet['5']['B']`, without having that i've picked the wrong cell, so that's no problem. 
But it still doesn't import all files, which is necessary, because later i want to import 5k+ Excel files. 
This is my code within the `foreach()` loop:

```
foreach($filenames as $names) {   
    $inputFileName = "echt/".$names;
    $inputFileType = IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $reader =  new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    $sheetData = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
    $merk = ($sheetData['5']['B'] !== '' ? trim($sheetData['5']['B']) : '');
    $chassis = ($sheetData['6']['B'] !== '' ? trim($sheetData['6']['B']) : '');
    $kenteken = ($sheetData['5']['F'] !== '' ? trim($sheetData['5']['F']) : '');
    $motornumber = ($sheetData['6']['F'] !== '' ? trim($sheetData['6']['F']) : '');
    $merktype = explode(' ', $merk);
    $cilindernumber = "";
    $eigenaar = "";
    $tel = "";
    // Check if file has already been imported
    $stmtselect = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM auto WHERE Kenteken = ?');
    $stmtselect->bind_param('s', $kenteken);
    $stmtselect->execute();
    $stmtselect->store_result();
    if($stmtselect->num_rows > 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO auto (Kenteken, Merk, Type, `Aantal Cilinders`,  `Chassis nummer`, `Motor nummer`, Eigenaar, Telefoonnummer) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('sssisssi', $kenteken, $merktype[0], $merktype[1], $cilindernumber, $chassis, $motornumber, $eigenaar, $tel);
        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->close();
            unset($stmt);

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? 
With kind regards,

**EDIT**
I found out what the problem was.
I imported an array which didn't always have 2 or more keys, so that didn't work out.. 
For people having the same problem:

```
if(!array_key_exists('1', $merktype)) {
  $val = '';
  array_push($merktype, $val);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how you can have 187 out of 123 files : "of the 123 files i've got, only 187 files are being imported"

Comment: correction: 87 files *** Also, i just edited the post

Comment: I notice that you don't bother checking for errors when you load the spreadsheet or try to insert the data. There are a number of possibilities: invalid XLS files, permissions problems reading the files, database indexes preventing duplicate values, etc.

Comment: @S.Imp Good call! I updated the code.

Comment: You still don't bother to see if you get anything valid when loading the spreadsheet: `$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);`